# Cannot get Braze InApp Messages to show up in my appllication

Tags: android, android-studio, braze

for some reason i cannot get Braze In App Messages to show up on my app

i can get normal push notifications fine so I assume the settings of how braze is implemented are correct

I'm also following the steps in
https://www.braze.com/docs/developer_guide/platform_integration_guides/android/in-app_messaging/integration/#step-1-braze-in-app-message-manager-registration

but I can't get the in app messages to show up on my activities
even when I'm making sure the line

```
com.braze.ui.inappmessage.BrazeInAppMessageManager.getInstance().registerInAppMessageManager(this);
```

is called

the events that I put in braze are
"as soon as the session is called"
and I add also "when notification is pressed"
just to make sure
but I see also the braze doesn't send it
so I'm not sure what is the reason

did anyone had any success from Braze > in-app messages?

if so how did you made it work ?